# Blur-Admin adding and using new npm package

Tags: angularjs, blur-admin

Hello I would like to add a new npm package to blur-admin.
For example I would like to use `ng-redux` with it.

Is there a proper documentation or an example of how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its easy. Run command line. Go to blur-admin folder and run:

```
npm install --save ng-redux
```